# How can I sort using a comparator with ties broken randomly?

Tags: java, sorting, random, comparator

I'm building a program that simulates a sports league, and, oftentimes, I want to sort teams by points, goal differential, etc. to determine things like which team gets promoted or which team gets preferential seeding in a tournament. But, sometimes, teams will be tied on all the criteria that I want to use, and I would like those ties to be broken randomly. I was previously using teams' ids (which are unique ints) to break ties, but I'd like to make it so that no team gets consistent preferential treatment in this sorting. I know that if I just let Java decide which of the tied teams will be placed in front of the other, it'll be very unpredictable, but I don't trust it to be actually random, and I'm worried that it'd inadvertently give some teams an advantage.

I've been using Collections.sort() with comparators to do my sorting, and I recently just went for it, and switched my comparators to use a random number as the final tiebreaker rather than the team ids. Here is the comparator in question:

```java
public static final Comparator<Team> pointsGDRand = new Comparator<Team>() {
    public int compare(Team a, Team b) {
        int result = b.getStats().getPts() - a.getStats().getPts();
        if (result == 0) {
            result = b.getStats().getGD() - a.getStats().getGD();
            if (result == 0) {
                result = R.boolNum();
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
};
```

I think the getter functions are self explanatory, but here's that random function:

```java
public static int boolNum() {
    return r.nextBoolean() ? 1 : -1;
}
```

But, just a bit ago (it look a long time for this error to pop up), I got this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!
```

I've read a little bit, and I think that the problem is likely that I had some instance where it figured out that A > B and B > C, but also A < C. This sheds some light on why it took so long for this error to pop up (it did maybe 20,000 sorts before it popped up with this error), because 2 teams getting the exact same score on **all** criteria seems like a pretty rare occurrence to me, much less 3 or more.

I'd rather not write my own custom sort, and I'd also rather not shuffle the list in question before each time I sort it (I feel like that'd be inefficient, but I'm confident it would work).

So, how can I make a comparator that breaks ties randomly (such that there's no risk of a team winning tiebreaks disproportionately) without risking that same error again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We need to compare tied teams using an extra attribute. This attribute needs to be constant for the life of a Comparator, but random from one Comparator to the next.

Create a new comparator each time you need to sort, and make sure that it behaves in a predictable, but random way:

```
class PointsGDRandComparator implements Comparator<Team> {
    // each comparator has a different seed
    private final long seed = new Random().nextLong();

    public int compare(Team a, Team b) {
        int result = b.getStats().getPts() - a.getStats().getPts();
        if (result == 0) {
            // every time we compare a particular team, the same random number will be produced
            long aValue = new Random(seed * a.getTeamId()).nextLong();
            long bValue = new Random(seed * b.getTeamId()).nextLong();
            return Long.compare(aValue, bValue);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

So each Comparator will have a different random `seed`, but each random decision will be the same, as we create new `Random` instances with a seed based on the Comparators `seed` and the ids of the two teams.

We are still sorting based on a function of team id (because we need to have a symmetric and transitive relation ship between comparing teams).

Two `Random` instances created using the same seed will produce the same sequence of random numbers. So when ever we compare the team with id `45` with another team, we'll create a `Random` instance with the seed `seed * 45` (where `seed` is constant for the lifetime of the Comparator), so the first time we call `nextLong()` on any instance of `Random` created with that seed we will always get the same number.

Here's a less tricksy way of doing the same thing. It assumes that `Team` has correct `hashCode` and `equals` implementations, so that we can use it as a key in a `Map`:

```
class PointsGDRandComparator implements Comparator<Team> {
    private final Map<Team,Long> tiebreakers = new HashMap<>();
    
    public PointsGDRandComparator(List<Team> teams) {
        Random r = new Random();
        for (Team t : teams) {
            tiebreakers.put(t, r.nextLong());
        }
    }

    public int compare(Team a, Team b) {
        int result = b.getStats().getPts() - a.getStats().getPts();
        if (result == 0) {
            return Long.compare(tiebreakers.get(a), tiebreakers.get(b));
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

The above solution is expensive, because it creates a Map the size of the teams list, and creates a random number for each team. Unless you have thousands of teams that won't matter, but we can make it cheaper by populating the Map lazily:

```
class PointsGDRandComparator2 implements Comparator<Team> {
    private final Map<Team,Long> tiebreakers = new HashMap<>();
    private final Random r = new Random();

    public int compare(Team a, Team b) {
        int result = b.getStats().getPts() - a.getStats().getPts();
        if (result == 0) {
            return Long.compare(
                    tiebreakers.computeIfAbsent(a, t -> r.nextLong()), 
                    tiebreakers.computeIfAbsent(b, t -> r.nextLong())
            );
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: I like the idea of using some sort of seed, but I don't see how this implementation wouldn't have the same issue. Would the seed remain stable through the sorting of an entire list? Because, from what I see, it looks like it'd regenerate for every comparison, which seems like it would make it continue to have the same issue as mine.

Comment: Each comparison uses a particular seed (`seed` * `teamId`), so it gets the same random number for a given team, every time that Comparator does a comparison involving that team. A new Comparator will have a different value for `seed` so it will break the tie in a different order. It's equivalent to taking your list of teams, and before sorting, giving each team a random team id.

Comment: It's a tad tricky, but this one does work. Any given team gets a unique 'tiebreaker long' - each team's tiebreaker long is stable for any given instance of this comparator (and whatever sort or TreeSet style thing you're doing here, it'll have a single comparator, therefore, stable tiebreaker longs). Hence, The scenario `A>B, B>C, but C>A` cannot occur - When comparing e.g. C and A, the tiebreaker longs are the same as when A or C are used in any other comparison.

Comment: NB: The seed value is constant __forever__ for any particular instance of Comparator, @RiggsMarkham. "Would the seed remain stable" - yes.

Comment: I've added a simpler implementation which uses more space (and probably more time too, as ties should be rare, but this generates a random number for each team up front)

Comment: And I've added one where the extra cost is proportional to the number of tied teams.

Comment: Thank you for your help with this. I certainly like the lazy map version. My only other thought before this was to make a new double field on team, and then before sorting a list, setting that field on each member of the list to a new random double. Your lazy map version would probably be a lot faster than that, right? (The lists are going to max out at ~50 teams).

Comment: With 50 teams any solution will take negligible time. Go with a solution which is easy to understand, and which you can easily see is correct before worrying about performance.

Comment: In my humble opinion the best feature of the lazy solution is that it introduces you to `computeIfAbsent`, and the worst feature is that it requires that you understand `computeIfAbsent` :-)

Comment: Lol, I actually had to do something sort of like that in another part of my code, and saw someone recommending:
seasonsByLeague.merge(l, 1, Integer::sum);
which ... I do not understand *at all*, so even just the title "computeIfAbsent" is better than that. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: One observation on comparing points.  Although it makes no difference unless the values compared are near the min and max of an Integer, I consider subtracting values a bad practice that might lead the unwary into problems down the road.  Since you use `Long.compare` to break the tie, why not use `Integer.compare` for the point comparison?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a different approach for randomly choosing tied teams

Use a map.

- store the teams that tied in a map, keyed by their score.  The map can be a tree map so it can be sorted.
- then iterate over the map and pick a team at random from each list.

Here are the teams before any processing.  The output is score and team name.

```
[3, A]
[1, B]
[2, C]
[0, D]
[0, E]
[1, F]
[1, G]
[2, H]
[2, I]
[2, J]
```

Now build the team map.

```
Map<Integer, List<Team>> team = teams.stream().collect(
   Collectors.groupingBy(t->t.getStats().getPts(),
        ()->new TreeMap<Integer,List<Team>>(Comparator.reverseOrder()),
            Collectors.toList()));
```

Here is the map of the teams, sorted in descending order of score.  The key is the score and the value is a list of teams with that score.

```
3=[[3, A]]
2=[[2, C], [2, H], [2, I], [2, J]]
1=[[1, B], [1, F], [1, G]]
0=[[0, D], [0, E]]
```

Now, just pick a random value from each list for a given score. This picks a value between `0` and the number of values in the list `(i.e. size())`

```
Random r = new Random();
for (Entry<Integer, List<Team>> e : team.entrySet()) {
    int pick = r.nextInt(e.getValue().size());
    System.out.println(e.getKey() + " " + e.getValue().get(pick));
```

for this run printed

```
3 [3, A]
2 [2, C]
1 [1, B]
0 [0, E]
```